# If the Delete link is clicked, show a JavaScript confirm pop-up box to the user

Tags: php, mysql

what should i write in the SCRIPT to make the row deleted

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function confirmation()
{
    var del=confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this record?");
    if (del==true){
   alert ("record deleted")
}
    return del;
}

</script>
```

inside the body

```
<td><a href="movie_list(delete).php?view&movid" onclick="return confirmation();">Delete</a></td>
```

and what should i do in in this part?

```
<?php

    if (isset(.....) 
    {
        ....
        header("Location: .....php");
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: Is this some kind of homework?

Comment: This is a job for ajax to trigger your php and on success show you the pop up

Comment: `movie_list(delete).php` – really, ( and ) in script filenames? Yikes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your delete button

```
onclick="return confirmDelete();"
```

Paste this one to header or footer of the page what ever.

```
<script>function confirmDelete() {
            if (confirm("Sure you want to delete ?") == true) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<td><button onclick="return confirmation();">Delete</button></td>
    <input type="hidden" name="movid" value="<?php echo 10; ?>">

<script type="text/javascript">

var movid = $('#movid').val();

function confirmation()
{
    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this record?"))
    {
        alert ("record deleted");
        window.location.href='movie_list(delete).php?movid='+movid;
    }

}
</script>
```

//on movie_list(delete).php

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET['movid'])) {
    header("Location:index.php");
}


?>
```